# C++/SDL: Fading out a surface already having per-pixel alpha information

Tags: c++, sdl, alpha, fading

Suppose we have a 32-bit PNG file of some ghostly/incorporeal character, which is drawn in a semi-transparent fashion. It is not equally transparent in every place, so we need the per-pixel alpha information when loading it to a surface.

For fading in/out, setting the alpha value of an entire surface is a good way; but not in this case, as the surface already has the per-pixel information and SDL doesn't combine the two.

What would be an efficient workaround (instead of asking the artist to provide some awesome fade in/out animation for the character)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way for you to achieve the result you want is to start by loading the `source` surface containing your character sprites, then, for every instance of your ghost create a `working` copy of the surface. What you'll want to do is every time the alpha value of an instance change, `SDL_BlitSurface` ([doc](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlblitsurface.html)) your `source` into your `working` copy and then apply your transparency (which you should probably keep as a float between 0 and 1) and then apply your transparency on every pixel's alpha channel.

In the case of a 32 bit surface, assuming that you initially loaded `source` and allocated `working` `SDL_Surface`s you can probably do something along the lines of:

```
SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, working, NULL);
if(SDL_MUSTLOCK(working)) 
{
    if(SDL_LockSurface(working) < 0) 
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

Uint8 * pixels = (Uint8 *)working->pixels;
pitch_padding = (working->pitch - (4 * working->w));
pixels += 3; // Big Endian will have an offset of 0, otherwise it's 3 (R, G and B)
for(unsigned int row = 0; row < working->h; ++row) 
{
    for(unsigned int col = 0; col < working->w; ++col) 
    {
        *pixels = (Uint8)(*pixels * character_transparency); // Could be optimized but probably not worth it
        pixels += 4;
    }
    pixels += pitch_padding;
}

if(SDL_MUSTLOCK(working)) 
{
    SDL_UnlockSurface(working);
}
```

This code was inspired from `SDL_gfx` ([here](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/software-mainmenu-14/4-ferzkopps-linux-software/19-sdlgfx)), but if you're doing only that, I wouldn't bother linking against a library just for that.

Comment: Looks great! I'll try this as soon as I get the time.

Comment: Worked, thanks! I also substituted 4s with working->format->BytesPerPixel and used SDL_BYTEORDER to check endianness.